# The cause of java "incompatible types"?

Tags: java, extends

```
import java.util.*;
class Poly{
    protected int[] coef = new int[1001];
    protected int[] exp  = new int[1001];
    protected int len;
    protected void attach(int c, int e){
        coef[len]  = c;
        exp[len++] = e;
    }
    protected void print() {
        for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
            System.out.print(coef[i]+" "+exp[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
class Add extends Poly{
    protected Add add(Add y) {
        int i,j;
        Add rel = new Add();
        for(i=0, j=0; i<len && j<y.len;) {
            if(exp[i] < y.exp[j]) {
                rel.attach(y.coef[j], y.exp[j]);
                j++;
            } else if(exp[i] > y.exp[j]) {
                rel.attach(coef[i], exp[i]);
                i++;
            } else{
                int c = coef[i] + y.coef[j];
                if(c != 0)
                    rel.attach(c,exp[i]);
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        while(i < len)
            rel.attach(coef[i], exp[i++]);
        while (j < y.len)
            rel.attach(y.coef[j], y.exp[j++]);
        return rel;
    }
}
class Mul extends Add{
    protected Add mul(Add y){
        Mul sum = new Mul();     //the following error has been solved by change this
                                 //Mul to Add , why?
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            Mul tmp = new Mul();
            for(int j=0; j<y.len; j++)
                tmp.attach(coef[i]*y.coef[j], exp[i]+y.exp[j]);          
            sum = sum.add(tmp);  //there are an error here
                                 //incompatible types
                                 //required : Mul
                                 //found : Add
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
public class answer{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        Mul d = new Mul();
        Mul e = new Mul(); 
        d.attach(6,4);
        d.attach(7,2);
        d.attach(2,1);
        d.attach(8,0);       
        e.attach(9,5);
        e.attach(3,2);
        e.attach(-1,1);
        e.attach(5,0);       
        System.out.println("Mul");    
        System.out.println("D(x)= 9 5 3 2 -1 1 5 0");
        System.out.println("E(x)= 6 4 7 2 2 1 8 0"); 
        System.out.print("F(x)=");
        d.mul(e).print();
    }
}
```

This is a simple `BigInt` sample which I practice my extends concept,

There are an error in Class Mul:

```
  sum = sum.add(tmp);
         ^
 incompatible types
 required : Mul
 found : Add
```

I solved this problem when I change the `Mul sum = new Mul(); to`Add sum = new Add ();` ,
in the same Mul class.

Why can it run? and why can't I use the original code `Mul sum = new Mul()` ?

the problem, I have searched in the Google always says that how to solved , but I want to know the concept.

Please, It's my first time to ask the question in English, Please be forgiving if you find anything offensive.

Thank you

Comment: It does not look like you really need to subclass `Poly` at all: both `mul` and `add` methods operate on the data from the base class, so it appears that you could "flatten" this entire hierarchy into a single class `Poly` without any loss of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Add.add` method returns an object of class `Add`. You are trying to assign a reference to this object into the variable `mul` that has type `Mul`. This cannot be permitted because `Add` is not a subclass of `Mul`. (In fact, `Mul` is a subclass of `Add`, but that's irrelevant.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `add` method is declared to return `Add` - but you're trying to assign the return value to a variable of type `Mul`. That's just not valid. If you change the declared type of `sum` to `Add` instead of `mul`, then that assignment is fine even if you initialize `sum` with a value of type `Mul` to start with.

It may be clearer to you if you separate out the method call from the assignment back to `sum`:

```
Mul sum = new Mul();
Mul tmp = new Mul();
...
Add result = sum.add(tmp);
sum = result; // This is the bit that's invalid
```

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here, but I'm pretty suspicious of a `Mul` class extending `Add` to start with...